# Do these foods affect healing after getting a tattoo?

Tags: nutrition

Where I live it is common knowledge that after getting a tattoo you should not eat certain types of food, e.g. seafood, chocolate, burgers. Apparently eating those foods will slow down the healing process and might even trigger an inflammation.

However when trying to find more info about this, I can only find unsourced blogs with conflicting information.

Some of those unsourced blogs (in Portuguese):

- [Artenocorpo](http://www.artenocorpo.com/1175/alimentos-que-prejudicam-a-tatuagem) says you should avoid fatty foods, condiments and chocolate for 30 days (translation from Portuguese):

  > The process of epithelial tissue reconstitution and cellular recomposition lasts for 28 days, and in this period some care must be taken, including food control.
  >
  > Fatty foods are first on the list. Fat damages the liver and slows down the healing process, which makes the region susceptible to infections for longer. Among the fatty foods are pork, chocolate, mayonnaise, egg and any kind of fry.
  >
  > Seasonings, condiments and preservatives are also enemies of recent tattoo care. Ketchup, salty snacks, cinnamon, pepper, salt, canned food, sausage and fast food should be avoided in the first thirty days.
  >
  > Fish and seafood also influence the healing of the tattoo. Although not scientifically proven, it is a strong recommendation from practitioners. After all, although healthy, fish and seafood are fatty foods.
- [umComo](https://beleza.umcomo.com.br/artigo/o-que-nao-pode-comer-quando-faz-tatuagem-28369.html) says you should avoid fatty foods, proteins (!) and especially chocolate (translation from Portuguese):

  > What can't we eat after the tattoo? The forbidden foods for those who have gotten a tattoo are those with many lipids, that is, very fatty foods. What foods are these? Meats, eggs, protein in general, oil, butter, margarine, but one that is special enemy of those who just got tattoos should be taken into consideration: chocolate. Those who just got a tattoo can not eat chocolate, because the high levels of fat in this food may end up popping the tattoo, making it difficult to heal the body modification.

Is there any evidence that after getting a tattoo you should not eat some types of food?